# uninstalling a specific version of a python package in a specific directory

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip, command-prompt

I want to uninstall the version 1.16.5 of numpy in a specific directory using pip in command prompt.
This is what I have written:

```
C:\Users\DSP>pip uninstall --target=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 numpy==1.16.5
```

This is what appears:

```
Usage:
  pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: --target
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/) for pip uninstall it doesn't look like `--target` is an option. Why are you trying to uninstall from a specific directory? If it was installed with conda then you should uninstall with conda as well. As for specifying the version, I don't think you can do that either as you should only have one version at a time anyway for that specific python install (except for virtual envs)